# Perl: Using =~ for case insensitve regex in if statement

Tags: regex, perl

Is there a minimal adjustment that i can do to the below code to cover cases where the ManagedElement String is of any case?

```
if($cmd =~ /^ManagedElement/){
    $cmd = "TreeNavigation";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, put an `i` at the end.

```
if($cmd =~ /^ManagedElement/i){
    $cmd = "TreeNavigation";
}
```

[Here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) is the documentation for future reference.